# Ignore dots when searching in the media library?

Tags: filters, search, media-library

As the title says, is it possible to ignore dots in search field in media library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ignore dots (`.`) in the search parameter `s`, for all *backend searches*, we can use:

```
/**
 * Ignore dots in all backend searches
 */
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( \WP_Query $q ) 
{
    if ( is_admin() && $q->is_search() )
        $q->set( 's', str_replace( '.', '', $q->get( 's' ) ) );
} );
```

We can further restrict it to the `list` mode of the *Media Library*:

```
/**
 * Ignore dots in all media library searches, for the 'list' mode
 */
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( \WP_Query $q ) 
{
    if (  
            is_admin() 
         && $q->is_search() 
         && $q->is_main_query() 
         && 'upload' === get_current_screen()->id 
         && 'list' === filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'mode' ) 
    )
        $q->set( 's', str_replace( '.', '', $q->get( 's' ) ) );     
} );
```

If we only want to target the *ajax searches*, that includes the `grid` mode of the *Media Library* and the *Insert Media* popup:

```
/**
 * Ignore dots in ajax searches
 */
add_filter( 'ajax_query_attachments_args', function( $args ) 
{
    if( isset( $args['s'] ) ) 
        $args['s'] = str_replace( '.', '', $args['s'] );
    return $args;
} );
```